# JFrame is empty when using JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

I have 2 Java classes, `Game` and `BaseComponent`.

I wanted to draw multiple components in my `JFrame`, but that doesn't work, since it will only display the last added component.

I think the solution is to add an `JPanel`, but that still doesn't quite work for me, since no object are being drawn, not even one.

### Game:

```
public class Game
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(300, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();

    JComponent component = new BaseComponent(0,0);
    JComponent component2 = new BaseComponent(1,1);

    jpanel.add(component);
    jpanel.add(component2);
    frame.add(jpanel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

### BaseComponent:

```
public class BaseComponent extends JComponent
{
  private int x, y;

  BaseComponent(int i, int y) {
    this.x = i;
    this.y = y;
  }

  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
     return new Dimension((x * 50) + 50, (y * 50) + 50);
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
     drawBaseComponent(g, x, y);
  }

  void drawBaseComponent(Graphics g, int x, int y)
  {
     g.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
     g.fillRect(x*50, y*50, 50, 50);
  }
 }
```

As you can see, this code adds one component to the the panel, which is being added to the `JFrame`, but it's completely empty;

[image]

EDIT:
When using prefered size, the application draws two green boxes but the position is not right, I expected them in the place of the two red boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default.  This will attempt to size any components to the `preferredSize`, which is, by default `0x0`, which is why, your component "appears" empty.

You will need to supply sizing hints, via `getPreferredSize`, in order to allow the layout management API to determine the best way to layout your component, for example

```
public class BaseComponent extends JComponent
{

 private int x, y;

 BaseComponent(int i, int i0) {
    this.x = i;
    this.y = i0;
 }

 @Override
 public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
     return new Dimension((x * 50) + 50, (y * 50) + 50);
 }

 @Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
    drawBaseComponent(g, x, y);
 }

 void drawBaseComponent(Graphics g, int xLeft, int yTop)
 {
   g.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
   g.fillRect(x*50, y*50, 50, 50);
 }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code, it works multiple-component wise, but the components are also placed completely at the wrong places.

Comment: Layout managers, layout managers, layout managers. Take some time and read through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to get a better understanding how component layout management works

Comment: That might be the thing, I cannot use an layout manager (assigment) but thanks for the help I will look into it ;)

Comment: Then I think you're approaching it from the wrong perspective.  You need a single component which can draw any number of rectangles, where ever you want them